# How can I get the exact answer of the maximum of this function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find the maximum of a fuction: $ f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+9}-\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{3} x+1} $.

I tried

```
 Maximize[Sqrt[x^2 + 9] - Sqrt[x^2 - Sqrt[3]*x + 1], x]
```

and I got

> {[Sqrt](9 + 
>        Root[{-3 + #1^2 &, 
>          243 - 567 #1 #2 + 1557 #2^2 - 702 #1 #2^3 + 485 #2^4 - 
>            71 #1 #2^5 + 35 #2^6 &}, {2, 2}]^2) - [Sqrt](1 - 
>        Sqrt[3] Root[{-3 + #1^2 &, 
>           243 - 567 #1 #2 + 1557 #2^2 - 702 #1 #2^3 + 485 #2^4 - 
>             71 #1 #2^5 + 35 #2^6 &}, {2, 2}] + 
>        Root[{-3 + #1^2 &, 
>          243 - 567 #1 #2 + 1557 #2^2 - 702 #1 #2^3 + 485 #2^4 - 
>            71 #1 #2^5 + 35 #2^6 &}, {2, 2}]^2), {x -> 
>      Root[{-3 + #1^2 &, 
>        243 - 567 #1 #2 + 1557 #2^2 - 702 #1 #2^3 + 485 #2^4 - 
>          71 #1 #2^5 + 35 #2^6 &}, {2, 2}]}}

The exact answer is $\sqrt{7}$.

How can I get the exact answer of the maximum of this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First set the function definition

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := Sqrt[x^2 + 9] - Sqrt[x^2 - Sqrt[3] x + 1]
```

---

**Method I**

The conventional method, by finding the stationary point first:

```
Solve[f'[x] == 0, x][[1]]
f[x] /. %
(f''[x] /. %%) < 0
```

> ```
> {x -> (3 Sqrt[3])/5}
> Sqrt[7]
> True
> ```

---

**Method II**

By using `ToRadicals` to transform `Root`:

```
Maximize[f[x], x] // ToRadicals
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[7], {x -> (3 Sqrt[3])/5}}
> ```